# Segmentation fault in a function of BST implementation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Here is my implementation to insert an item in a Binary search tree.

```
void insert(struct Node* root,int item){
if(root==NULL){
    root = newNode(item); // newNode is a function which creates new node, initialized it with item & return pointer of the new node.
}
if(item < root->item)
    insert(root->left,item);
else
    insert(root->right,item);
}
```

But I am clueless why it is giving segmentation fault with following invoking in driver program?

```
struct Node* root = NULL;
insert(root,50);
```

Comment: I recommend you do some research about *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: Have you tried pointing a debugger at your binary to see where the crash occurs?

Comment: @MortenJensen Debugger was closing the IDE repeatedly. couldn't use.

Comment: Please show us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have *infinite recursion*.

With the initial call then `root` will be a null pointer, meaning you will create a new root node. Then we get to the check `if(item < root->item)` which will be false, leading to the program executing the `else` clause and calling `insert` recursively.

If `newNode` sets the `left` and `right` pointers to `NULL`, then the whole thing will start over, creating a new node and going to the `else` clause and calling itself recursively.

The solution is *another* `else`, as in

```
if (root == NULL) {
    ...
} else if (item < root->item) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

You would have found out the problem *very* quickly if you just used a *debugger* to either catch the crash or to step through the code. In the future, start by using a debugger first to catch the crash, and locate where and when it happens, and examine the function call stack.

---

If on the other hand `newNode` does *not* initialize the `left` and `right` pointers of the node structure, then you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which can often lead to crashes.

Dynamic allocation functions like `malloc` does *not* initialize the memory it allocates. The contents of the memory is *indeterminate*. Dereferencing such a pointer leads to said UB (Undefine Behavior).

This too could have been detected quickly with the help of a debugger.

---

Finally a third possible reason for your crashing, if you fixed the above to problems, is that when you pass an argument to a function in C, it is passed *by value*. That means the value is *copied* into the argument, and the argument inside the function is like any other local variable, and all changes to the argument (assignments) are lost once the argument goes out of scope when the function returns.

That means after the initial call to `insert` the variable `root` will *still* be a null pointer.

The solution to this is mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, but still showing segmentation fault. Actually I was trying using IDE debugger which was closing the IDE repeatedly.

Comment: @Rohit. Updated my answer with two other possible problems. After fixing the first, the last (third) is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks. It was 3rd mistake. :-)